# Downloading youtube video using pytube

Tags: python, web-scraping, video, youtube, pytube

I am using pytube for downloading YouTube video but except 1080p I am able to download every resolution video (144p to 720p). What is the possible reason?

Here is what I have tried:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from io import BytesIO

def download_video(url, quality):
    global title
    buffer = BytesIO()
    yt = YouTube(url, use_oauth=False, allow_oauth_cache=True)

    try:
        title = yt.title
        video = yt.streams.get_by_resolution(quality)
        video.download(filename='Video.mp4')
        video.stream_to_buffer(buffer)
        return "Done"
    except Exception as e:
        return e


url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVqFyinDgE4'
quality = '720p'

print(download_video(url, quality))
```

When I pass `quality = 720p` it return 'Done' but when I pass `quality = 1080p` it return *None type object has no attribute download*.

Comment: May you add your `import`s and an URL to reproduce your issue please?

Comment: Does [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/youtube-videos-download-using-python-codes-3b6183825f0b) help?( *"...Note that the highest resolution for the combined audio and video file is HD 720p, which is the limit for such Progressive Stream."* )

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I have edited the code, when I pass 720p it return "Done" and if I pass 1080p it returns "something went wrong"

Comment: maybe first use without `try/except` to see FULL error message instead of `"Something went wrong!"`

Comment: based on duplicated question - you may have to use filter with `progressive=False`  lik `video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=False, subtype="mp4", resolution=quality).first()` or without `progressive` like `video = yt.streams.filter(subtype="mp4", resolution=quality).first()`

Comment: @PerpetuallyConfused thank you for your comment the article was really helpful

Comment: @furas i have used `video = yt.streams.filter(subtype="mp4", resolution=quality).first()` and problem got solved thank you

Comment: @furas This question is different form the one you are saying duplicate because the user was not able to get any video and in my case I was having problem with only 1080p resolution. Many future users may have same problem.

Comment: duplicate question is similar problem - I found solution using link to source code in this duplicated question. And other user had problem because tried to get `144p` which had only `progressive=False`, and you want to get `1080p` which also has only  only `progressive=False`

Comment: @furas I got you but only experienced one will get that not the newbie.